# Syntax error in database rules while deploying

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

While deploying my website to firebase,i get a syntax error in database rules showing:

> 2:5: Expected rules property.

I am listing down the code in json

```js
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
    },
    "database": {
        "rules": "firebase.json"
    },
    "emulators": {
        "auth": {
            "port": 9099
        },
        "database": {
            "port": 9000
        },
        "hosting": {
            "port": 5000
        },
        "ui": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The rules value should point to a rules file, not at the `firebase.json` file itself. Something like:

```
"rules": "database.rules.json"
```

That rules file must define [valid database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). For example:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```